# Probability of 2 base-120 units digit having units digit 1 when multiplied and writtein in base 120

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The question goes as follows-

Two base-$120$ units digits (not necessarily different) are chosen randomly and their product is written in base $120$. What is the probability that the units digit of the base $120$ product is $1$?

I approached it like this-

Let the units digits be $a$ and $b$, so, $ab ≡ 1 \pmod {120}$

This means that $b$ would be $a$'s modular inverse, and since a number has only 1 modular inverse in a given base, there would be only one $b$ for each $a$. $a$ could possibly be the numbers from $0$ to $119$ inclusive, this gives $120$ possible pairs of $a$ and $b$. The total possible pairs of $a$ and $b$ would be $120^2$, which would give the probability $1/120$. But when I ran a C program with the following code, I got the answer as $32/120^2$, which means there are only $32$ possible values for $a$. Why is this? Where did I go wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int count = 0;
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 120; j++)
        {
            total++;
            if (i*j % 120 == 1)
                count++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d/%d", count, total);
}
```

Comment: Not every number has a multiplicative inverse modulo $120$.  What would be the inverse of $2$ or $3$?  Which numbers have inverses?  (Think first about which ones cannot.)

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you! I realize my mistake now

Comment: 1) using C,  2) forgetting a coprimality check, 3) not reducing to 1/450